# CURL: using curl commands for AEM Prod instance

Tags: curl, aem, wcm

I have an AEM production server instance and I need to execute cURL command to delete a user, but it's saying access denied.
Please help me with it.

`curl -u username:password -FdeleteAuthorizable= http://AEMURL:4502/home/users/d/delete`

I'm able to do this when I'm working on localhost. But I'm not able to do the same on production instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be several reasons, your production AEMURL may have something in the way - such as apache (dispatcher) or a proxy that is denying these sort of requests, or more likely this node is restricted with the user that you are using to log in with.

You will need to check the permissions for this node.

Are you actually logged into the production box with SSH or is this command also issued from your local PC?

In the error message is there any indication what has actually told you your access is denied?

Comment: It was simply a permission issue of not having the access rights to delete the node. Made changes and now it works fine. Thanks!